# What is the best way to generate RF in SkyFactory 4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-skyfactory

what do you usually use to power your RF Machines in SkyFactory 4? I use the Simple Generators Mod but is there much more efficient than Simple Generators in consuming fuel to produce RF?

Comment: Before someone jumps to conclusion that this is a software recommendation or tech support request - no, this is a game strategy question. SkyFactory 4 is a modpack, many mods included in it provide similar functionality in different ways. RF is an important resource and there are many ways of producing it, multiple mods providing their own production methods, vastly differing in complexity, efficiency and requirements, each with own quirks.

Comment: If you choose wrong, you'll go down a rabbit hole of a week of building a massive contraption that in the end makes as much RF as a trivial single-block solution from another mod. Or explodes taking out half of your base with it.

Comment: @SF. "The best mod" contradicts your point, though.

Comment: "best" or "more efficient" in terms of what? Output? Space? Early accessability? I'm voting to close this one as "needs details or clarity" until a proper criteria for "best" is given.

Comment: @user1337. i edited my question, thanks for the feedback guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple generators are a good early game RF source but once you get more advanced, use the nuclear reactors or solar panels.

Answer (score 0):

Fully upgrade at least 9 culinary gens with speed modifiers then build a massive pig farm (With a spawner you can craft) using mob mashers that have fire aspect, sharpness, and looting upgrades. If you do it right, you will get hundred if not thousands of cooked porkchops just lying there. Wire up a vacuum hopper to the culinary generators. If you did it correctly, the spawner that you placed (Also, put a dragon egg in the spawner with some sugar, ghast tears, fermented spider eye and clocks) will spawn pigs (Because the spawners in minecraft default to pigs) and the pigs will die on the mob mashers. The vacuum hopper will suck the items up and put the cooked porkchops into the culinary generators, which will produce stupid amounts of power.